# append content of all files in a directory to a single file

Tags: vb.net

I have a directory with more than one file with random file name.

First I get all the files with

`myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetTempPath & "Files\")`

To go through my files and append there content I tried first to put them to an array:

```
For Each tempFile As String In myFiles 
   arryString = arryString  & (File.ReadAllLines(tempFile )) 'There Is Error here
Next
```

What is the right way of doing this (Copy all Text Files to a single text file)?

Comment: You can't concatenate arrays with `&`.  I would suggest using a `StreamReader` for the input file, read a line, then write that line to the new file (via `StreamWriter`).  Rinse and repeat until done.

Comment: if you use a `List<string>` to store the data you can use the `.AddRange` method and change the string array into a List with linq.  However, this will be memory intensive and I agree a `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` should be used to reduce memory needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on my comment, try something like this:

```
Using writer As New StreamWriter("newFile.txt")

    For Each tempFile As String in myFiles

        Using reader As New StreamReader(tempFile)

            While Not reader.EndOfStream

                writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine())
            End While
        End Using   
    Next
End Using
```

The above code creates a `StreamWriter` to the new file.  Then it loops through the files in the directory, and for each file it creates a `StreamReader`.  Then it reads each line of the file (until `EndOfStream` is true) and writes it to the new file.

I used `Using` statements to ensure the writer and reader are properly disposed of.